# Mapping HTTP request value to object in Sprint Boot application when field and value has different field name?

Tags: spring-boot

This instance of class `AuthorizationRequest` is created during HTTP request, params are sent in query string.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authorize", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String authorize(
            @Valid AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest,
            BindingResult result
    ) {
```

I would like to use this code, this is an example parameter from `AuthorizationRequest` class:

```
@NotEmpty
@JsonProperty("client_id")
private String clientId;
```

but new instance has a filed `clientId` empty, because in query string there is a value for this parameter under `client_id` parameter.

Is there some way how to tell Spring which parameter from HTTP request should use for one particular field of created instance? I need to solve problem with different naming `clientId and`client_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with own implementation of `org.springframework.web.method.supportHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

**Resolver** implementation:

```
public class AuthorizationRequestResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AuthorizationRequestResolver.class);

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().equals(AuthorizationRequest.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
                                  ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                                  WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) webRequest.getNativeRequest();

        AuthorizationRequest authRequest = mapFromServletRequest(request);
        return authRequest;

    }

    private AuthorizationRequest mapFromServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = new AuthorizationRequest();
        authorizationRequest.setClientId(request.getParameter("client_id"));
        authorizationRequest.setRedirectUri(request.getParameter("request_uri"));
        authorizationRequest.setResponseType(request.getParameter("response_type"));
        authorizationRequest.setScope(request.getParameter("scope"));
        authorizationRequest.setState(request.getParameter("state"));
        return authorizationRequest;
    }

}
```

and **cofiguration** class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebappConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new AuthorizationRequestResolver());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a setter to handle each kind of clientId. Keep in mind that if both clientId and client_id is specified that it is unknown which will take precedence.

```
//These methods will allow clientId or client_id 
to be used as arguments setting the same field this.clientId
public void setClient_id(String client_id) {
    this.clientId = client_id;
}

public void setClientId(String client_id) {
    this.clientId = client_id;
}
```

I tested this with a post and a get

```
get - http://localhost:8080/authorize?clientId=2&username=someusername
get - http://localhost:8080/authorize?client_id=2&username=someusername

post - http://localhost:8080/authorize 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Body: clientId=2&username=someusername

or Body: client_id=2&username=someusername
```

I was only able to have @JsonProperty("client_id") to be recognized when I annotated AuthorizationRequest with @RequestBody and then used application/json instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded